# R shiny reactive plotly graph

Tags: r

I would like to make a plotly graph on shiny, very simple... but i don't get it... it's a candlestick graph... I load data from yahoo finance, i put it in a list and i create a dataframe following what we want see... but it doesn't work, it load all except the graph with the sentence :
"First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data"

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
trim<-Sys.Date()- months(3)
#floor_date(ajd,"month")

comp<-c("CAC 40","Total","Sanofi","BNP","LVMH","Airbus","Axa","L'Oreal","Air Liquide","Danone","Vinci","Schneider","Societe Generale","Kering","Orange")
ref<-data.frame("^FCHI","FP.PA","SAN.PA","BNP.PA","MC.PA","AIR.PA","CS.PA","OR.PA","AI.PA","BN.PA","DG.PA","SU.PA","GLE.PA","KER.PA","ORA.PA")
colnames(ref)<-comp

for (i in 1:length(comp)){
  stock<-ref[1,i]
  stock<-as.character(stock)
  getSymbols(stock,src="yahoo",from=trim,to=Sys.Date())
}
for (i in 1:length(comp)){
  ref[,i]<-as.character(ref[,i])
}
ref[,1]<-c("FCHI")

data<-list()
for (i in 1:length(comp)){
  data[[i]]<-get(ref[,i])
}



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Top companies of CAC 40 Analysis"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("Companies"),
      selectInput("titre","Company:",
                  choice=colnames(ref)),
      hr(),
      helpText("Data from yahoo finance")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h3("Evolution du cours"),
       plotlyOutput("graph")
    )
  )
))


library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  sortie<-reactive({
    compa<-input$titre
    temp<-data.frame(Date=index(data[[compa]]),coredata(data[[compa]]))
    colnames(temp)<-c("Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
  })

  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(sortie,x=sortie$Date,type="candlestick",
            open=sortie$Open,close=sortie$Close,high=sortie$High,low=sortie$Low)
    layout(title="Quaterly evolution")
  })


})
```

If someone find something i made wrong...

Comment: Reactive data frames need to be called like a function: `sortie()`

Comment: yes, i forgot it but it doesn't work yet... i changed too sortie$Date etc by temp$Date etc but it doesn't work yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there wasa a couple of problems with your code
 first the `data` was not a named list so I changed the line

```
temp<-data.frame(Date=index(data[[compa]]),coredata(data[[compa]]))
```

to

```
temp<-data.frame(Date=index(data[[which(compa == comp)]]),coredata(data[[which(compa == comp) ]]))
```

to get the right index of `comnp`

then you were not returning the data frame from `sortie` but rather the vector of the column names. I just added a call to `temp`  at the end of `sortie` to fix this. The last thing Ryan already mentioned in his comment with the brackets after `sortie`. Below follows a working version of the server code. I haven't changed anything else.

```
function(input, output) {

  Sortie<-reactive({
    compa<-input$titre
    temp<-data.frame(Date=index(data[[which(compa == comp)]]),coredata(data[[which(compa == comp) ]]))
    colnames(temp)<-c("Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
    temp
  })

  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    sortie <- Sortie()
    plot_ly(sortie,x=sortie$Date,type="candlestick",
            open=sortie$Open,close=sortie$Close,high=sortie$High,low=sortie$Low) %>% 
      layout(title="Quaterly evolution")
  })


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was that but i added the names of companies in the list in ui code :

```
data<-list()
for (i in 1:length(comp)){
  data[[i]]<-get(ref[,i])
}
names(data)<-comp
```

So after my original code works with that :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  sortie<-reactive({
    compa<-input$titre
    temp<-data.frame(Date=index(data[[compa]]),coredata(data[[compa ]]))
    colnames(temp)<-c("Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
    temp
    })

  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    sortie<-sortie()
    plot_ly(sortie,x=~Date,type="candlestick",
            open=~Open,close=~Close,high=~High,low=~Low)%>%
            layout(title="Quarterly evolution")
  })


})
```